# Dask: Sorting truly lazily

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dask, dask-dataframe

If I have a dataset with unknown divisions and would like to sort it according to a column and output to Parquet, it seems to me that Dask does at least some of the work twice:

```py
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd

def my_identity(x):
    """Does nothing, but shows up on the Dask dashboard"""
    return x

df = dask.datasets.timeseries()
df = df.map_partitions(my_identity)
df = df.set_index(['name'])  # <- `my_identity` is calculated here, as well as other tasks
df.to_parquet('temp.parq') # <- previous tasks seem to be recalculated here
```

If `my_identity` was computationally demanding, then recomputing it would be really costly.

Am I correct in my understanding that Dask does some work twice here? Is there any way to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation below may not be accurate, but hopefully helps a bit.

Let's try to get into dask's shoes on this. We are asking dask to create an index based on some variable... Dask only works with sorted indexes, so Dask will want to know how to re-arrange data to make it sorted and also what will be the appropriate divisions for the partitions. The first calculation you see is doing that, and dask will store only the parts of calculation necessary for the divisions/data-reshuffling.

Then when we ask Dask to save the data, it computes the variables, shuffles the data (in line with the previous computations) and stores it in corresponding partitions.

How to avoid this? Possible options:

1. `persist` before setting the index. Once you persist, dask will compute the variable and keep it on workers, so setting index will refer to the results of that computation. There will still be reshuffling of the data needed). Note that the documentation suggests persisting [after](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html) setting the index, but that case assumes that the column exists (does not require separate computation).
2. Sort within partitions, this can be done lazily, but of course it's only an option if you do not need a global sort.
3. Use plain `pandas`, this may necessitate some manual chunking of the data (what I tend to use for sorting).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This is interesting, why does `persist` not re-calculate `my_identity` as well? Especially compared to `to_parquet`, which does. That I don't understand.