# Call to .compute() after .persist() on the same dataframe triggers complete re-evaluation

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I have an issue with Dask's compute and persist methods. I understand the difference between the two methods. However, when using them as below, it doesn't behave as I expect.

```
feature_dataframes = [list of indexed dataframes]
features = dask.dataframe.multi.concat(feature_dataframes, axis=1)
features = features.persist()

[code making computations on features]

features.compute().to_parquet("features.parquet")
```

What I see in the dashboard is that the dataframes in `feature_dataframes` get computed twice. What I would expect is that the call to `features.persist()` causes `features.compute()` to be a very cheap operation.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce the behaviour using the `dask.datasets.timeseries()` dataset? A reproducible example will make it much more likely you'll get good answers.

Comment: Btw, you do not need to `compute` before calling `to_parquet`. Calling `compute` Pandas write the whole dataset from memory. This will likely be slower than writing a partitioned dataset directly from Dask. Finally: is the `to_parquet` necessary to reproduce the behaviour? Does it not happen without it? –

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried to reproduce the error with the random dataset, but I didn't succeed. The reason I call compute is because I want to export the features dataframe as 1 Pandas dataframe. Removing the .compute() call didn't work. However, I was able to resolve the issue by calling .persist() on the dask bag that is converted to the indexed dataframe using to_dataframe(). Apparently, it was recomputing everything again when setting the index.

Comment: If there's a `set_index` (or other `shuffle`-inducing operation) somewhere down the path, then perhaps the double work you're seeing is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68686134/dask-sorting-truly-lazily) and is not actually related to things being recomputed at `compute` again? The thing is: `compute` shouldn't recompute anything after `persist` AFAIK, but perhaps it's not actually what happens in your case?

Comment: Interesting answer to the post you linked, thanks. It indeed seems to be related. I am not 100% sure though, because to solve the issue I had to persist the bag prior to calling `to_dataframe()` and not prior to `set_index()` (which follows right after the `to_dataframe()` call)